# Извлечение единицы измерения числа

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеются инженерные данные (число и единица измерения)

```
1) 135.9 kJ/mol
2) 285 MPa (12.3 Atm)
3) 0.0277 W/(m*K)
4) 54 W/(m K)
5) 1750 °C
```

Требуется получить только единицы измерения - **kJ/mol**, **MPa**, **W/(m*K)**, **W/(m K)**, **°C**.

Единица измерения может содержать символы /, *, (, ), символ пробела, знаки градуса.

Написал регулярное выражение, которое успешно [обрабатывает](https://regex101.com/r/eN1pA6/2) первые два случая:

```
\d+\.\d+\s(\w+[\/]\w+)|
\d+\s(\w+[\/]\w+)|
\d+\s(\w+)
```

но понимаю, что оно учитывает только частные случаи (один знак деления например) и не учитывает наличия множества особых символов (как в случае 3 и 4). как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Проблема решается через разбиение строки по пробелу и взятием второго элемента полученного списка. Без regexp.

Comment: Хм, смотрите. Может быть такая единица измерения 54 W/(m K). Пробел разбивает ее, и мы возьмем некорректные данные. Дополнил вопрос

Comment: И что же это за единица измерения такая? Точнее, что значит выражение "m K" с математической точки зрения?

Comment: В данном случае W/(m K) - коэффициент теплопроводности. выражение "m K" означает перемножение величины метра и кельвина, допускается же не записывать знак умножения, а подразумевать его. и еще в этом случае разделили пробелом чтобы не спутать с приставкой десятичной доли

Comment: А во-втором случае какая единица измерения должна быть получена?

Comment: MPa - мегапаскаль, тут уже М - как приставка идет по системе СИ

Comment: На наличие пробелов повлиять не смогу. Данные изначально такие получены.Тут где-то явно используется  знак умножения, а где-то пробел. Закономерностей нет. Единственная закономерность - единица измерения идет после числа, основные случаи указал в примере

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eJ7bL1/1 - рекурсивные скобки не поймет.

Comment: странно, на сайте все отрабатывает. но при попытке прогнать чере шелл и модуль re на питоне, ни одного совпадения. напишите, пожалуйста, отдельным ответом, я вам хоть плюс поставлю, у вас полезный ответ

Comment: Что-то вообще не понятно, на что расчитано ваше выражение, оно почти все выбирает

Comment: А вы не учитываете размерности вроде `m^2/s` (единица измерения, например, температуропроводности)? Просто любопытно =)

Comment: ну, в списке размерностей не увидел таких знаков. но в ответе от @Автомат и Золото можно расширять регулярное выражение с учетом знака степени, которое вы привели. в целом предоставленные данные не содержат никаких закономерностей (где-то используюся знаки умножения, где-то нет, в другом месте числа в СИ, в другом - как попало записаны), и ваша ситуация вполне может проявится. тут уже остается только костылировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/[a-zA-Z].*/g
вроде как подходит под все случаи

Comment: даже ни один не обрабатывает. что значит флаг /g?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lR1oA3/1      /g Глобальный значит поиск во всем тексте.

Comment: про глобальный флаг догадывался, но в документации по модулю re для python не нашел этого флага

Comment: почти все обрабаывает регулярка, только в символы надо еще включить латинский алфавит и знак градуса

Comment: и смотрите, для второго случая ваша регулярка охватывает MPa (12.3 Atm)

Comment: а надо ? чтобы только mpa?

Comment: да, только ту размерность, что идет после первого числа, в вопрос указал жирным шрифтом. с своем регулярно выражении пытался, это учесть. часть данным идут с таким дополнительным значением в скобках, но оно не нужно

Comment: [a-zA-Z°].?[a-zA-Z/()*]+

Comment: сначала обрадовался, что все обработало. беру первую группу из совпадений и получаю свою размерность. но 4 случай все поломал. возвращает ['W/(m', 'K)']. размерность разбита на две части и первая группа это только кусок

Comment: ваш ответ можно считать подходящим, спасибо. но придется добавить костыль, уже не вижу адекватных решений. просто будут объединять элементы листа в одну строку и отрезать нежелательные куски.

Answer (score 1):

по идее должно помочь `/([0-9]) (.*)/g` если в числительном значении не будет пробелов. На выходе массив, вторым значением которого и будут единицы измерения. У меня все обработало 
Можна попробовать `/[0-9]|\.{1}/g` - поиск всех чиселл и точки..со строки вырезать их просто

Comment: Почти, для второго значения возвращает "MPa (12.3 Atm)" вместо MPa

Comment: может поможет второй варант..в пхп, например, str_replace использовать и заменить вхождения на пустую строку

Answer (score 1):

Я бы так сделал:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?\s(.*)
```

Во второй группе `group(2)` будут единицы изменения.

[Тест](https://regex101.com/r/kV1dL6/1)

Comment: почти все отлично кроме второго случая, возвращает "MPa (12.3 Atm)" вместо MPa